# Source class (PATH) for (PATH) generation does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException):

```
Source class "\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CapabilityInterface" 
  for "Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CapabilityRepository" 
  generation does not exist.
```

where as in my di.xml I have mentioned

```
<preference for="Vendor\ModuleName\Api\CapabilityRepInterface"
            type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CapabilityRepository" />
```

when I run

```bash
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

It doesn't give any error but when i inject this interface in my controller the above error is shown.

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Vendor\ModuleName\Api\CapabilityRepInterface;

class Temp extends Action
{
protected $capabiliyRepo;

public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    CapabilityRepInterface $capabilityRep
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->capabiliyRepo = $capabilityRep;
}

public function execute()
{
    $this->capabiliyRepo->checkAbility("my_project_create_project");
}
}
```

Comment: can you include your controller in your post

Comment: Added please check

Comment: @magefms i have added the controller. can you check now?

Comment: Is that the whole code of your controller? try changing to `return $this->capabiliyRepo->checkAbility("my_project_create_project");`  instead of `$this->capabiliyRepo->checkAbility("my_project_create_project");`

Comment: try this instead `use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Vendor\ModuleName\Api\CapabilityRepInterface;

class Temp extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
  protected $capabiliyRepo;

  public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    CapabilityRepInterface $capabilityRep
  )
  {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->capabiliyRepo = $capabilityRep;
  }

  public function execute(){
    return $this-> capabiliyRepo->checkAbility("my_project_create_project");
  }
}`

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Vendor\ModuleName\Api\CapabilityRepositoryInterface in /var/www/vhosts/work/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Comment: Now this error is showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92603/discussion-between-magefms-and-avesh-naik).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the path of the Repository class. It should be under root of Model directory.

```
<preference for="Vendor\ModuleName\Api\CapabilityRepositoryInterface"
            type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\CapabilityRepository" />
```

You can also check the Magento core repository for reference.

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php

Comment: Same error. Source class "\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\CapabilityInterface" for "Vendor\ModuleName\Model\CapabilityRepository" generation does not exist.

Comment: CapabilityRepository class should implements the CapabilityRepositoryInterface. Can you double confirm ?

Comment: class CapabilityRepository implements \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\CapabilityInterface, please check that you added \ in-front of the interface.

Comment: CapabilityRepository class should implements the CapabilityRepositoryInterface. Yes i implemented it.